# Zip multiple observables of different types

Tags: java, rx-java

*How to zip multiple observables of different types at once with rx Java?*

```
Observable<Action> actionStream = getAction();
Observable<UserInfo> ownerStream = getOwner();
Observable<List<UserInfo>> relatedUsersStream = getUsers();
Observable<Double> score = getScore();

//Question: how to merge all relusts at once nad call `getResult`?
getResult(action, owner, relatedUsers, score);
```

---

**UPDATE:** found solution. But the broblem is that `getResult` returns `Observable<Result>` instead of `Result`, and zip method don't want to compile.

```
Observable.<Action, UserInfo, List<UserInfo>, Double, Result>zip(
  (action, owner, relatedUsers, score) -> getResult(action, owner, relatedUsers, score)
);
```

Comment: Perhaps zip into a tuple type?

Comment: @akarnokd sure, but appache has implementations only for `Pair` and `Triple`. I'll finish with custom 4th-Tuple, pretty ugly code

Comment: It's pretty normal you write your own  composite objects for reactive use. If you can't find a lib with tuple4+, then write your own class.

Comment: is there any particular reason for getResult() to return observable?

Comment: there is no static Observable.zip can you correct your code example?

Comment: @OfekRon there is http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip(java.lang.Iterable,%20rx.functions.FuncN)

Comment: @OfekRon the definition `public static <R> Observable<R> zip(` says about returned type. The input type is `? extends Observable<?>` which allows you to pass observables of different types

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk isee that now, all good! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is rxjava-joins project http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex/rxjava-joins/0.22.0 with and/then/when functionality. You can make something like this:

```
  @Test
  public void rxJoins() throws Exception {

    Observable<Integer> ints = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
    Observable<String> strs = Observable.just("a", "b", "c");
    Observable<Boolean> bools = Observable.just(false, false, true);

    Plan0<Data> threeItems = JoinObservable.from(ints).and(strs).and(bools).then(Data::new);
    JoinObservable.when(threeItems).toObservable().toBlocking().subscribe(System.out::println);
 }

 private static class Data {
    private final int val1;
    private final String val2;
    private final boolean val3;

    public Data(int val1, String val2, boolean val3) {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
        this.val3 = val3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "val1=" + val1 +
                ", val2='" + val2 + '\'' +
                ", val3=" + val3 +
                '}';
    }
}
```

More info here: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html

Comment: will check ouyr solution in few hours. Thank you!

Comment: I think that Observable.zip is better solution since it doesn't require external libs and do the same